# Omnet++ Error setting parameter in child Class and calling it in another child Class

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am trying to set a parameter in **PassiveQueueBase** which is child class and call it in another child class **PriorityScheduler** for Base Class **IPassiveQueue**.

PriorityScheduler is inherited from SchedulerBase which has a pointer (inputQueue) pointing at who ever is of type **IpassiveQueue** and going to invoke PacketEnqueued() function to PriorityScheduler. This is shown in this code

```
class INET_API SchedulerBase : public cSimpleModule, public IPassiveQueue, public IPassiveQueueListener
{
    public:
    virtual void packetEnqueued(IPassiveQueue *inputQueue) override;
};
```

**Note:** IpassiveQueue.h has no .cc file it is an interface file for many other classes.

What I tried to do is shown below,

```
class INET_API IPassiveQueue
{
  public:
    simtime_t sendWindowStart;
    simtime_t sendWindowEnd;
    virtual void setWindows() {};
};

class INET_API PassiveQueueBase : public cSimpleModule, public IPassiveQueue
{  protected:
    void setWindows(simtime_t SWS,simtime_t SWE);
};

void PassiveQueueBase :: setWindows(simtime_t SWS,simtime_t SWE)
{   SWS = 3;  SWE = 4;                  
sendWindowStart = SWS;               
sendWindowEnd = SWE;             
};

bool PriorityScheduler::schedulePacket()
{
IPassiveQueue *pqueue;
pqueue->setWindows();
sendWindowStart = inputQueue->sendWindowStart;
sendWindowEnd = inputQueue->sendWindowEnd;
}
```

I had an error by running the simulation as shown below

> Simulation terminated with exit code: 139 Working directory:
>   /home/usrname/omnetpp-5.0/samples/inet/examples/mysimulation Command line:
>   opp_run -r 0 -n ..:../../src:../../tutorials -l ../../src/INET
>   --debug-on-errors=false omnetpp.ini

Also I have exclamation mark on this line

```
pqueue->setWindows();
```

with this note

> ‘Pqueue’ may be used uninitialized in this function
>   [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

Comment: Are you intend to use your modified queue's class as typical `OMNeT++` queue? If yes, you should prepare a new class which inherits from `PassiveQueueBase` and `IQueueAccess`, where `PassiveQueueBase` is the class *already existed* in INET (not your class).

Comment: well It was one step what I am showing in this question, because I want this variable to show up in DropTailQueue which again inherited from QueuePassiveBase. I am using DropTailQueue in the internal Queue of the switch. So I won't say it is my personal class still I am using omnet++ Queue.

Comment: In your question you have presented `IPassiveQueue` class which is **different** that `IPassiveQueue` from `INET`. If you want to use an own queue I strongly suggest preparing a new class which inherits from `PassiveQueueBase`, and `IQueueAccess`. In this new class you may add own variables as well as own behaviour.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I got your point now. Will work on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not allocated `pqueue` yet and you are using it.

```
IPassiveQueue *pqueue;
```

this one still points on unknown location on memory.

to fix this you can allocate it using `new`

```
IPassiveQueue *pqueue = new IPassiveQueue;
```

and make sure to delete it using `delete`

```
delete pqueue;
```

you could also allocate it using smart pointer which will be more safe

```
std::unique_ptr<IPassiveQueue> pqueue(new IPassiveQueue);
```

Comment: For that line `IPassiveQueue *Pqueue = new IPassiveQueue;` I got error **invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘inet::IPassiveQueue’** For the last line I am getting syntax error trying to find the one for omnet. Will advise you once done.

Comment: I just knew that it is not possible in omnet++ to use new with interface Ned file

Comment: Sorry late reply, it says your IPassiveQueue is an abstract class, you cannot create an object of an abstract type.  You should implement all pure virtual function in IPassiveQueue

Comment: No problem tyt, you are correct. I actually can create a separate function only to create the pointer as for the case of pointer inputQueue, but i ended using inputQueue itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well I thought about using inputQueue itsself as pointer instead of creating new pointer on the function that exactly the same as in the child class but empty and it worked.

```
class INET_API PriorityScheduler : public SchedulerBase
{
  protected:
    virtual bool schedulePacket() override;
    simtime_t sendWindowStart;
    simtime_t sendWindowEnd;
    simtime_t SWS;
    simtime_t SWE;
};

bool PriorityScheduler::schedulePacket()
{
    inputQueue->setWindows( SWS, SWE);
    sendWindowStart = inputQueue->sendWindowStart;
    sendWindowEnd = inputQueue->sendWindowEnd;
}

class INET_API IPassiveQueue
{
  public:
    simtime_t sendWindowStart;
    simtime_t sendWindowEnd;
    virtual void setWindows(simtime_t SWS,simtime_t SWE) {};
}

class INET_API PassiveQueueBase : public cSimpleModule, public IPassiveQueue
{
  protected:
    virtual void setWindows(simtime_t SWS,simtime_t SWE) {};
}

void PassiveQueueBase::setWindows(simtime_t SWS,simtime_t SWE)
{   SWS = 1; SWE=5;
sendWindowStart = SWS;
sendWindowEnd = SWE;
}
```